# Unknown Error in P5.js?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video, p5.js

I want to video processing using p5.js library. but own code doesn't work when using an external video element by **select()** function.
But the code does work when used **createCapture()** function instead **select()**

```
//index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="assets/vendor/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/p5/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/p5/p5.dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/p5/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/scripts/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="snapshot">
        <video id="video"  autoplay=""></video>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

//script.js

$(document).ready(e => {
    window.currentEffect = 0;
    let v = $("#video");
    effects = [{
        name: "Normal",
        effect: (p) => {
            let v;
            p.preload = () => {};
            p.setup = () => {
                v = p.select("#video");
                if (p.select("#canvas") === null) p.createCanvas(v.width, v.height).id("#canvas");
                else {
                    p.select("#canvas").remove();
                    p.createCanvas(v.width, v.height).id("#canvas");
                }
                p.pixelDensity(1);

            };
            p.draw = () => {
                p.background(51);
                p.translate(p.width, 0);
                p.scale(-1, 1);
                p.loadPixels();
                for (let y = 0; y < p.height; y++) {
                    for (let x = 0; x < p.width; x++) {
                        let i = (x + y * p.width) * 4,
                            r = v.pixels[i + 0],
                            g = v.pixels[i + 1],
                            b = v.pixels[i + 2],
                            rb = (r + g + b) / 3;
                        p.pixels[i + 0] = rb;
                        p.pixels[i + 1] = rb;
                        p.pixels[i + 2] = rb;
                        p.pixels[i + 3] = 255;
                    }
                }
                p.updatePixels();

            };
        }
    }];
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: false,
            video: {
                mandatory: {
                    minWidth: v.width(),
                    minHeight: v.height(),
                    maxWidth: v.width(),
                    maxHeight: v.height()
                }
            }
        })
        .then(stream => {
            v.attr({
                "src": window.URL.createObjectURL(stream),
                "autoplay": "true"
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
     new p5(effects[0].effect);
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me what happens if you do `v = p.select("#video").elt;`? Do you see any errors in the JavaScript console? Can you link to a page running this code, or a jsfiddle?

Comment: when use v = p.select("#video").elt; JavaScript console show this error:
v.loadPixels is not a function

Comment: Hmm, gotcha. Can you link to the page running this code, or better yet a jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5aq9L6Lg/1/

Comment: the error above in video element  because v.loadPixels() not load video pixel but p.loadPixels() is working